# Searching files and returning name of parent dir with most matches?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Say I have a search mask like `"*casting?00*"` that should corresponds to a directory in a tree, by the amount of filename matches. How do I return only the subdirectory with most filename matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop recursively over the subfolders, count the matching files in each (save them to a temporary file for further processing). Sort it and get the last line, separating counter and foldername:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del tmp.csv 2>nul
for /r /d %%a in (*) do (
set "count="
  for /f %%b in ('dir /b "%%a\*casting?00*" 2^>nul ^|find /c /v ""') do (
  set "count=    %%b"
  echo !count:~-4!,%%a >>tmp.csv
     )
)

sort tmp.csv

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=, " %%a in ('sort tmp.csv') do set "folder=%%b" & set "count=%%a"
echo --- %count% findings in %folder% ---
```

Note: If more than one folder have the same max. amount of matching files, this will give you the last one only.

**Edit** to use an array instead of a file (less readable in my opinion, but just to show, how it can be done):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set index=0
for /r /d %%a in (*) do (
  set "count="
  set /a index+=1
  for /f %%b in ('dir /b "%%a\*casting?00*" 2^>nul ^|find /c /v ""') do (
    set "count=    %%b"
    set "Array[!index!]=!count:~-4!,%%a
  )
)
set Array
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=, " %%x in (
    '(for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set Array'^) do @echo %%a^)^|sort'
  ) do set "count=%%x" & set "folder=%%y"
echo --- %count% findings in %folder% ---
```

Comment: You could avoid the temp file.  Before the for loop `set count=0` and `set folder=Not found`.  Inside the for loop `if /i %%b gtr !count! set count=%%b&&set folder=%%a`.

Comment: @avery_larry correct, but having the complete data available might be useful too. (for example `type tmp.csv |find " %count%,"` would show all folders that have the same max count of matches and `type tmp.csv |find " 0,"` would show all folders that have no matching files)

Comment: @avery_larry this should be an answer

Comment: @Stephan You could do all of that with an array of variables.  Though most likely something that sophisticated would not be done in .cmd.  And I'm not saying your answer is bad because it uses a temp file.  That's why I just added a comment with a slight variation.

Comment: @avery_larry an array was indeed my first idea. But using the folders as variable names, sorting is difficult (has to be done manually) and using the count as name would lose folders with the same amount of matches.

Comment: The array can be designed in a way that allows for `set arraystub|sort` to do the sorting and keep all the folders.  Again, I'm not saying your answer is bad.  But as an interesting side discussion, or in the event that temp files are not feasible . . .

Comment: @avery_larry: only if you set the counter as variable name (Array name) (with leading zeros instead of spaces), losing entires (overwriting previous ones with the same count of matches) or with `set array|sort +n`, assuming there will be less than 10 folders. Added a working array-solution, but IMHO not worth the trouble.

Comment: @Stephan there is way more folders than 10

Comment: @Bricktop: both of my codes cover that. The discussion above was a more academic one about different possible approaches.(in `cmd` sorting (especially with the `sort` command is alphanumeric. We have to use some tricks to do correct numeric sorting)

Comment: @Stephan why is `sort tmp.csv` there twice?

Comment: @Bricktop: the line `sort tmp.csv` is for troubleshooting/verifying only. It can safely be removed. (same with the `set Array` line in the second code)

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat apologize as I've hijacked this question a bit.  This isn't meant to be a competing answer -- rather a continuation of the discussion using an array of variables.

I should probably use the term "pseudo-array" for my approach.  I would replace the traditional incremental array index with the count of files.  I would add the foldername to the variable name to eliminate duplicates.

There are plenty of "gotcha's".  Which is pretty much always true in CMD.  Special characters will cause problems.  With the method I will show, the characters `"`, `=`, `]`, and `[` will definitely cause problems.  Another issue is the length of the command line and variable name length.  If your paths get to be really long then this code will choke.  I *think* it's somewhere around 8,000.

Generally, to get numbers to sort alphabetically, you must pad them with leading characters (commonly zeros or spaces).  When numbers will be arbitrary and incremental, my personal preference is to start with a large number like 10000 instead of 0 or 1.  In this scenario, though, I am not using incremental numbers but instead am using the count of files as a pseudo-index.  I prefer math to padding zeros, so I just add 1,000,000 to the count.  This will keep it alphabetical as long as there are 8,999,999 files or fewer in any subfolder.  I'm pretty sure the maximum possibility within CMD math limitations would be starting with 1,000,000,000 which allows for around 1,147,483,648 files.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Just in case there are any array variables already defined
:: we'll clear them first.
for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set a1 2^>nul') do set %%a=
for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set a2 2^>nul') do set %%a=

for /r /d %%a in (*) do (
   for /f %%b in ('dir /b "%%a\*casting?00*" 2^>nul ^|find /c /v ""') do (
      set /a filecount=%%b + 1000000
      set "a1[!filecount!]%%~pnxa=%%b"
      set "a2[%%~a]=%%b"
   )
)

:: Things you can do with this . . .

:: Basic list in order from largest count to smallest
set a1|sort /r

:: List the "first" folder with the most files
echo.
echo The "first" folder with the most files:
for /f "tokens=2 delims==]" %%a in ('set a1 ^| sort /r') do echo %%a & goto :continue

:continue

:: The largest file count
echo.
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('set a1 ^| sort /r') do (
   set /a maxfiles = %%a - 1000000
   echo The most files in any subfolder is !maxfiles!.
   goto :continue
)

:continue

:: All of the subfolders that share the max number of files:
echo.
echo.
echo.
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set a1 ^| sort /r') do (
   set /a maxfiles = %%a - 1000000
   echo All the subfolders with the maximum of !maxfiles! files . . .
   for /f "tokens=2 delims==]" %%b in ('set a1[%%a]') do echo.  %%b
   goto :continue
)

:continue

:: The subfolders with 0 files
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo The subfolders with 0 files . . .
for /f "tokens=2 delims==]" %%a in ('set a1[1000000] 2^>nul') do (
   set nonempty=yes
   echo.  %%a
)
if not defined nonempty echo.  There are none.

:: CSV style output
echo.
echo.
echo.
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=]=" %%a in ('set a1 ^| sort /r') do echo "%%a",%%b
```

The a2 array is not used here but just an example of a matching array arranged differently.

Comment: Two arrays with the same info (redundant) and `a1` is even redundant in itself (contains count  two times)

Comment: There isn't an infinite loop.  There isn't a `goto :continue` line anywhere after the last `:continue` label.

Comment: a2 is indeed redundant.  I should have clarified originally in my post that it is simply an example of setting up a matching array arranged differently.  In other usage scenarios you can use the "answer" from the first array to pull information from the second array.

Comment: Setting a1 to count is indeed redundant also.  However, I have to set the variable to something and I thought the count (without adding 1,000,000) could be useful in other use cases.  It could have been set to 0 for every variable.  Again though, this code is meant as much to be an example of creative variable/array usage as it is to be an answer to the original question.  As this example largely revolves around the ability to sort things, the values that the variables are set to are largely not useful.

Comment: "endless loop": my fault. I didn't copy the whole code by accident.